# Return a unique result from a list based on a percent chance

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, random, percentage

I have a two long lists.
Example:

```
good = ["Good thing1", "Good thing2", "Good thing3", "Good thing4", "Good thing5", ...]
bad = ["Bad thing1", "Bad thing2", "Bad thing3", "Bad thing4", "Bad thing5", ...]
```

The number of players can change:

```
players = 5
```

Each player has a 43% chance that a good thing will happen (or a 57% chance that a bad thing will happen). No two players can have the same good or bad outcome.

I tried to do a weighted outcome like this:

```
weighted_outcome = good * 43 + bad *57
random.sample(weighted_outcome, 5) # Where 5 is the number of players
```

but I get duplicates. If I do this as a set, then the weighted outcome becomes unweighted, as in this example:

```
weighted_outcome = good * 43 + bad *57
random.sample(list(set(weighted_outcome)), 5) # Where 5 is the number of players
```

Am I correct in assuming that the only way to make this weighted is to create a new unique weighted list? like in this example where I have a 70% good outcome and a 30% bad outcome:

```
weighted_result = []
weighted_result.append(random.sample(set(good), 7)
weighted_result.append(random.sample(set(bad), 3)
print(weighted_result)
```

I feel like this is still wrong, because at 70% there should still be a chance that every player had something good happen and a low chance that every player had something bad happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you use `if`? Here's an example

```
from random import randint
good_things = [good1, good2]
bad_things = [bad1, bad2]
players = [player1, player2]
temp_good_things = good_things[:]  # coping the lists
temp_bad_things = bad_things[:]
chance_for_good = 47
for player in players:
    if randint(0, 100) <= change_for_good:
        good_thing = get_random_element(temp_good_things)
        temp_good_things.remove(good_thing)
        player.do_thing(good_thing)
    elif:
        bad_thing= get_random_element(temp_bad_things)
        temp_bad_things.remove(bad_thing)
        player.do_thing(bad_thing)
```

Key to have unique `things` for your players is to remove used element from the list. In order to save base `things` I'm coping the lists into temporary lists.

Comment: This doesn't work for allowing me to have unique values for each player.

Comment: @Chad you must have missed this part: "And then remove this good/bad thing from the list."

Comment: @Chad I have edited the first version to show you more complete solution.

Comment: I think your right and this will work. When I get home I'll try this out and let you know! Thanks a lot

Comment: Took me a while to get back to this, but the code worked with some tweaking to it. You miss spelled some stuff, but I fixed that and modified it to work with a co-routine I'm using. Thanks for your help.